# wpf datagrid combobox column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have trouble reading the field. I have tried in different ways but still can not. I want to read the value that the user selected the following 3 values.

Code in XAML

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn X:Name="dgcbc" Header="Wynik"/>
```

Code in C #

```
List<string> list = new List <string> ();
lista.Add ("Prize");
lista.Add ("Draw");
lista.Add ("Lost");
dgcbc.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to read the value that the user selected the following 3 values."?  And what is your issue exactly?

Comment: Don't do it this way. In WPF try to use bindings, it's way easier: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sample might help you in understanding how listbox can be used.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }        
}
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="myGrid" Margin="10">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />             
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Gender" 
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Gender}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  <Button Name="ShowPersonDetails"  
          Content="Show Person Details" 
          Width="200" Height="30"  
          Click="ShowPersonDetails_Click" Margin="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class WPFDataGridComboBox : Window
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<string> Genders { get; set; }

    public WPFDataGridComboBox()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { Name = "ABC", Gender = "Female" },
            new Employee() { Name = "XYZ" }
        };

        Genders = new List<string>();
        Genders.Add("Male");
        Genders.Add("Female");

        InitializeComponent();
        myGrid.ItemsSource = Employees;
        Gender.ItemsSource = Genders;
    }

    private void ShowPersonDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in Employees)
        {
            string text = string.Empty;
            text = "Name : " + employee.Name + Environment.NewLine;
            text += "Gender : " + employee.Gender + Environment.NewLine;
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd change the `myGrid.ItemsSource = Employees;` and `Gender.ItemsSource = Genders` to bindings instead.

Comment: Yes, I understand how it works, and I wrote the rest of the code. Everything works. Thank you and best regards for your help RonakThakkar. :)

Comment: @RonakThakkar - I am very new to WPF (infact MS technologies) and was looking for this solution for sometime now. This really helped me. I think you should write blog article about it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to enable multi selection in the combobox inside DataGridComboBoxColumn.
Following code project does the same.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and